# Cannot find module 'mongoose-unique-validator'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a todo list App with passport authentication, but I get this error when I run node app:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose-unique-validator'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/walid/Todo list API/models/user.js:2:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/walid/Todo list API/app.js:7:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

This is my App file, and the error says that it can't connect to mongoose:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const config = require('./config/database');
const passport = require('passport');

mongoose.connect(config.database);
let db = mongoose.connection;

// Check connection
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected to mongoDB');
});
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing npm package? If it's not finding it, then maybe it wasn't installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the mongoose library is utilizing mongoose-unique-validator , usually they install it in their inner package.json but looks like something is wrong. Try to install it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The module mongoose-unique-validator that's mentioned in the error is a submodule of mongoose. It's possible that it didn't get installed when you installed the mongoose module.

You can try reinstalling by typing one of the following:

### Yarn

`yarn add mongoose`

### NPM

`npm install mongoose`